# How to apply css to id generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am adding the index to star dynamically in html.

My html:

```
<i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" id="star[111]" style="float:right;color:#D9CFBE"></i>
```

Script(in angularjs):

```
$scope.AddItem = function(obj) {            
        $("#star["+obj.Sno+"]")[0].style.color = "#FE5105";         
}
```

But i am getting error: cannot read property style of undefined

Kindly help me out plss

Comment: Be sure that you are getting the DOM instance of your object, so after you have that, you can apply the `.style.*` properties to it.

Comment: why don't you try an id with the form star.111 or star_111 instead of star[111] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a selector, `[` and `]` delimit an [*attribute selector*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). If you want to match them as part of an id, you must escape them.

Note that you must also escape `\` characters within JavaScript strings.

```
"#star\\[" + obj.Sno + "\\]"
```

It is generally better to avoid using CSS meta characters in ids and class names to begin with.